# How to get the ClickCount Property

Tags: c#

Here is a problem I have encountered:

I have created my own event, delegate, and method and when an event is raised I want to pass to it Mouse X and Y position (for that I have found `MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y` properties to take care, however I can't access ClickCount property directly.

I know there is `MouseButtonEventArgs.ClickCount` but I don't want to use built in event I would like to use my own and access directly ClickCount property as above event does.

Wondering if its even possible? Thank you for any kind of tip on this matter! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's possible.  That property only exists as part of the Args, and is only generated by the system events that pass it.

You could synthesize the event and get the count, but honestly, I doubt it's worth the work.  Just use the events that the framework provides, and pile on from there.  Reinventing the wheel is only going to make more and harder work for you in the end.

Comment: so you suggesting to use events and then just storing mouse counts in my own declared variable?

Comment: Basically, yes.  The mechanics of that will depend upon your goal.  Essentially, you need to capture the fact that a click occurred, what kind of click, and then time the MouseDown events such that you can discern single, double, triple, etc. click events.  And a way to determine when it needs reset.  This can get very complicated.